# mocha run tests twice

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tdd, mocha.js

I have a several tests for node js express application written in coffeescript run under Mocha control. 
Unfortunately mocha runs all my tests twice, becouse in the same directory I jave .coffee and .js files. The .js files are generated by my editor automatically together with .map files. That's quite handy if I need to debug something.

How can I filter that only .coffee or .js are executed from directory not both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your package.json, create entries like the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test-coffee",
    "test-js": "mocha -R spec test/*.js",
    "test-coffee": "mocha -R spec test/*.coffee"
  }
```

Now you can run `npm test`, `npm run test-js`, or `npm run test-coffee`. If you have tests in subdirectories, you will want to use the find command to run just the subtests you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that when I use for instance mocha -R spec test/*.coffee then it sees only test located directly under test/ directory. The files burried deeper are not processed. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Yes, just use `find test -name "*.js" -type f -exec mocha -R spec {} +` and `find test -name "*.coffee" -type f -exec mocha -R spec {} +`

Comment: Yes this is true it will works but mocha in such case takes each test individually and the final report about success and failures is not integrated.

Comment: No, if you ended with a `/` it would do one mocha test a time. With a `+` at the end it runs a single mocha instance across all the files, which is what you want.

Comment: You may use `| xargs` instead of `-exec` : `find test -name "*.js" -type f | xargs mocha -R spec`.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha by default runs files with pattern: `test/*.{js,coffee}` which includes both coffee and js files. In your case, it will find both coffee and js files of each test, thus your tests are run twice.

You may want to set the file pattern explicitly, something like:

```
mocha -R spec "test/*.js"
```

If you have tests in subdirectories, you can use globstar (**) in your pattern like this:

```
mocha -R spec "test/**/*.js"
```

Note the use of double quotes. If you omit double quotes they will be interpreted by shell and it may not be able to match files in subdirectories. Using double quotes passes the pattern to mocha, and mocha handles it correctly.